# I've been scammed in accepting a TeamViewer remote control session from a stranger. How do I abort it?

Tags: windows, security, teamviewer, remote-control, remote-assistance

*This did not actually happen to me.*

When playing Minecraft online it is not rare to see hackers in action. But also it is not rare to see moderators & server owners trying to fight them by inspecting player's behaviour.

On some particular servers moderators do *in vivo* hack checks by having the player authorize a TeamViewer remote control session during which they search the users hard disk for hack tools or hacking clients. If players do not comply they are usually banned.

While this is a good method to thwart hackers in action, the privacy invasion associated with this type of control concerns me: I trust a moderator on a game server, but not on my own PC.

Assuming I actually wanted to keep playing on such a server, I would like to protect me from a random 9-year old messing with my system with my same privileges, so I was wondering if ― in the case of a TeamViewer (QuickSupport) session ― the user is able to quickly abort the remote control session by means of a key combination.

I know I can push a button with mouse or pull power/net plugs, but I'd like to know if a simple solution exists that does not involve mouse or cables.

Answer (score 1):

At a bare minimum, actually interrupting the network connection will end their mouse and keyboard control. If you have only a wired network connection, pulling out the cable is *guaranteed* to end the session; with wifi, if your computer has a physical switch, turning it off will end the session. Likewise, shutting off the computer will terminate the session; QuickSupport doesn't support unattended connections, it seems, so that would be sufficient.

On the other end of things, the TeamViewer manual says that the remote computer (i.e. the one being controlled, not the one doing the controlling) has a button on the TeamViewer panel to end all active remote control sessions; if your computer is being controlled, pressing that button would terminate the control.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a short-cut to that button...